# XML reading problem with WP7

Tags: c#, parsing, windows-phone-7, linq-to-xml

i'm trying to create an application with Windows Phone 7, which displays data from a specific URI, but it won't work. I'm stack,help me please.
This is my XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<weather module_id="0" tab_id="0" mobile_row="0" mobile_zipped="1" row="0" section="0">
    <forecast_conditions>
        <day_of_week data="lun."/>
        <low data="28"/>
        <high data="38"/>
        <icon data="/ig/images/weather/mostly_sunny.gif"/>
        <condition data="Partiellement ensoleillé"/>
    </forecast_conditions>
    <forecast_conditions>
        <day_of_week data="mar."/>
        <low data="27"/>
        <high data="39"/>
        <icon data="/ig/images/weather/sunny.gif"/>
        <condition data="Temps clair"/>
    </forecast_conditions>
    <forecast_conditions>
        <day_of_week data="mer."/>
        <low data="25"/>
        <high data="38"/>
        <icon data="/ig/images/weather/mostly_sunny.gif"/>
        <condition data="Ensoleillé dans l'ensemble"/>
    </forecast_conditions>
    <forecast_conditions>
        <day_of_week data="jeu."/>
        <low data="24"/>
        <high data="33"/>
        <icon data="/ig/images/weather/mostly_sunny.gif"/>
        <condition data="Ensoleillé dans l'ensemble"/>
    </forecast_conditions>
</weather>
```

This is my c# code:

```
namespace WEATHER2
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        // Constructeur
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("Gweather.xml");
            var x= from c in doc.Descendants("forecast_conditions")
            select new Weather_Element()
             {
                 Day = (string)c.Attribute("day_of_week").Value,
                 Low = (string)c.Attribute("low").Value,
                 High = (string)c.Attribute("high").Value,
                 Condition = (string)c.Attribute("condition").Value
              };
             listBox1.ItemsSource = x;
        }

        public class Weather_Element
        {
            string day;
            string low;
            string high;
            string condition;

            public string Day
            {
               get { return day; }
               set { day = value; }
            }
            public string Low
            {
               get { return low; }
               set { low = value; }
            }
            public string High
            {
               get { return high; }
               set { high = value; }
            }
            public string Condition
            {
               get { return condition; }
               set { condition = value; }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is not working?  Is 'x' not being populated with your data or are you just not seeing anything in your UI.  If it is your UI then you will need to post the XAML too.

Comment: By the way: If you use C# 3.0 and above, try Auto-Implemented Properties in your `Weather_Element` class:
`public string Day {get; set;}`.
See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx for more information.

Comment: Thanks guys!But I was wondering how to read data from an URI,using web service(let's assume it's the same data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to get attribute values from the an element without attributes.

```
var x = from c in doc.Descendants("forecast_conditions")
select new Weather_Element()
{
    Day = c.Element("day_of_week").Attribute("data").Value,
    Low = c.Element("low").Attribute("data").Value,
    High = c.Element("high").Attribute("data").Value,
    Condition = c.Element("condition").Attribute("data").Value
};
```

The element `c` of type `forecast_conditions` has an element `day_of_week`. Then this element has an attribute `data`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `forecast_conditions` don't have any attributes, they have child elements instead which then have `data` attributes. So instead of

```
        var x= from c in doc.Descendants("forecast_conditions")
        select new Weather_Element()
         {
             Day = (string)c.Attribute("day_of_week").Value,
             Low = (string)c.Attribute("low").Value,
             High = (string)c.Attribute("high").Value,
             Condition = (string)c.Attribute("condition").Value
          };
```

use

```
        var x= from c in doc.Descendants("forecast_conditions")
        select new Weather_Element()
         {
             Day = (string)c.Element("day_of_week").Attribute("data"),
             Low = (string)c.Element("low").Attribute("data"),
             High = (string)c.Element("high").Attribute("data"),
             Condition = (string)c.Element("condition").Attribute("data")
          };
```